# Search results pagination logic in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a search site which will enable users to search for their favorite restaurants in the city. My database is setup and my search page is setup. I was also able to get the search results returned. However, I am having trouble with pagination logic and unable to get the results. I suspect the MySQL query needs to be tweaked but I am at a loss on what the changes are.

Here is my Search.php code:

```
<title>Results</title> <link href='./style.css' type='text/css' />
<style>b,p {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Web Light', 'Segoe UI Light', 'Segoe UI Web Regular', 'Segoe       UI', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Helvetica Neue',
Arial; color:#000; font-size:18px;

}

body { font-family: 'Segoe UI  Light', 'Segoe UI Light', 'Segoe UI Web
Regular', 'Segoe UI', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial;
color:#000; font-size:22px;

} a { text-decoration:none; color:#47a3da} a:hover {
text-decoration:underline; color:black }
* { margin:0px; padding:0px }

ol.timeline   { list-style:none}ol.timeline li{
position:relative;border-bottom:2px #dedede dashed; padding:12px;
}ol.timeline li:first-child{}     .morebox    {   font-weight:light;
  color:#333333;  text-align:center;  border:solid 1px #333333;
  padding:9px;    margin-top:9px;     margin-bottom:9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;-webkit-border-radius: 7px;     }   .morebox a{
color:#333333; text-decoration:none}  .morebox a:hover{ color:#00688B;
text-decoration:none}
#container{margin-left:55px; width:780px } </style>

<?php

$start = 0; $per_page = 4;

if(!isset($_POST['query'])) {

$page = 1;

}  

else {

$page = $_POST['query'];

}

if($page<=1) {

$start = 0; 

}

else {

$start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;

}

####### databse connection  ########   $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "database", "password");
mysql_select_db("database", $con) or die("no"); $sql = "SELECT
hotelname,address,comments,preview,cuisname FROM database.Hotel INNER
JOIN HotelCuisine ON Hotel.id = HotelCuisine.hotel_id INNER JOIN
Cuisine ON Cuisine.id = HotelCuisine.cuisine_id WHERE keywords LIKE
'%$page%'";

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)); $num_pages =
ceil($num_rows / $per_page); $sql .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";

?>

<body>

<?php

//####### Fetch Results From Table ########

$result = mysql_query($sql); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ $hotelname = $result['hotelname'];  $address = $result['address']; 
$comments = $result['comments'];  $preview = $result['preview']; 

?>

<?php

####### echo the result from table ########

echo "<br>Name: <b>$hotelname</b><br>";  echo "Location:
$address<br>";  echo "$comments<br>"; echo "<a
href=$url>$preview</a><br>"; 

}

?>

</body>

<?php

####### Math OF +1 and -1 for the page ########

$prev = $page - 1; $next = $page + 1;

echo"<hr>"; echo "<a href='?page=$prev'>prev</a> "; echo " <a
href='?page=$next'>next</a> ";

?>
```

Comment: Where is the value of $_POST['query']? Also can you query work without the LIMIT clause?

Comment: Yes, the query is working without the LIMIT clause.

Comment: Have u tried to print the content of $sql? What it it?

Comment: This is what I get when i echo $sql   SELECT hotelname,address,comments,preview,cuisname FROM database.Hotel INNER JOIN HotelCuisine ON Hotel.id = HotelCuisine.hotel_id INNER JOIN Cuisine ON Cuisine.id = HotelCuisine.cuisine_id WHERE keywords LIKE '%biryani%' LIMIT 0, 421

Comment: The query looks OK to me. What if you run thr query on command line or in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: PixelsTech, thank you for your comments. Could you explain to me the numbers listed after 'LIMIT' specifically 0,421. where is the number 421 coming from? Is there something wrong with my calculation? Could you suggest a different code logic?

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure the code you pasted here is the one when you echo the $sql? From my understanding, the query should be

```
SELECT hotelname,address,comments,preview,cuisname FROM database.Hotel INNER JOIN HotelCuisine ON Hotel.id = HotelCuisine.hotel_id INNER JOIN Cuisine ON Cuisine.id = HotelCuisine.cuisine_id WHERE keywords LIKE '%biryani%' LIMIT 0, 4
```

Here 0 is the start index of the result and 4 is the number of rows return.

Also, your code is not efficient when you retrieve the number of rows. This one can be optimized.

If I am going ti implement it, I would use below logic:

```
<?php
$start = 0; 
$per_page = 4;

if(!isset($_POST['page'])) {
    $page = 1;
} else {
    $page = intval($_POST['page']);
}


####### databse connection  ########   
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "database", "password");
mysql_select_db("database", $con) or die("no"); 

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) AS num_of_rows FROM database.Hotel INNER
        JOIN HotelCuisine ON Hotel.id = HotelCuisine.hotel_id INNER JOIN
        Cuisine ON Cuisine.id = HotelCuisine.cuisine_id WHERE keywords LIKE
        '%$_POST['query']%'";

$num_rows = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql))["num_of_rows"];
$num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $per_page);

$sql = "SELECT hotelname,address,comments,preview,cuisname FROM database.Hotel INNER
        JOIN HotelCuisine ON Hotel.id = HotelCuisine.hotel_id INNER JOIN
        Cuisine ON Cuisine.id = HotelCuisine.cuisine_id WHERE keywords LIKE
        '%$_POST['query']%' LIMIT ".($page-1)*$per_page.",".$per_page;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<body>
<?php
//####### Fetch Results From Table ########
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $hotelname = $result['hotelname'];  
    $address = $result['address']; 
    $comments = $result['comments'];  
    $preview = $result['preview']; 
    ####### echo the result from table ########
    echo "<br>Name: <b>$hotelname</b><br>";  
    echo "Location: $address<br>";  
    echo "$comments<br>"; 
    echo "<a href=$url>$preview</a><br>"; 
}

####### Math OF +1 and -1 for the page ########
$prev = $page - 1; 
$next = $page + 1;

echo"<hr>"; 
echo "<a href='?page=$prev'>prev</a> "; 
echo " <a href='?page=$next'>next</a> ";
?>
</body>
```

Again I would suggest you to run the $sql on command line or in phpMyAdmin first to check whether the query is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I executed the $sql in phpMyAdmin and it was successful. So I incorporated the new sql statements to my search.php page but now I get a 500 Internal Server Error after I enter the search query and submit.

Comment: @kay5 500 error may be caused by many reasons. I believe what you can do first is to hardcode the query and see the result. This can help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hardcoding the sql statement with the search keyword works in phpMyAdmin but in real time the results page gives the same Internal Server Error. This line of code $num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $per_page); which I dont seem to be using $num_pages anywhere in the code?! Could you check the code that you pasted in your reply? Should $num_pages be used somewhere in the php code?

Comment: $num_pages is not uaed right now. But the issue you are wncountering is not related to this line. I believe the 500 error is related to something else other than the query

Comment: Can it be because I have HTML code inside the .php file? I am really at a loss here. I have tried multiple variations but nothing seems to be working...

Comment: html is allowed in php file. why not just create a simple php file which just runs the sql with LIMIT to make it simpler